# Why can't I import a let definition from a package, in a SystemVerilog module?

Tags: system-verilog, let, register-transfer-level

I would like to put the following definitions in a default package, which I include in all my other SystemVerilog modules:

```
let max(a,b) = a > b ? a : b;
```

But, when I try to use the imported `let` definition in a module, I'm told that I'm attempting to use a non-local function definition and VCS errors out.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The simple example works with no issues. Make sure that the package is always compiled **before** it is imported. Do correct import from the package either as `pkg::*` or `pkg::max`. Or use it as `pkg::max(a,b)` directly without import. And yes, use the compiler which supports this syntax.

```
package pkg;
  let max(a,b) = a > b ? a : b;
endpackage:pkg

module top();
  import pkg::*;
  
  int a = 1,b = 2;
  initial begin
    $display("max of %d and %d is %d", a, b, max(a,b));
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks, @Serge! Which SystemVerilog compiler did you use to verify this code?

Comment: synopsys VCS as well as aldec, cadence and mentor  (all from eda playground)